# Advanced pgrep-like process search in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I need to find the pid of a certain java process in bash on linux.

If there's only one java process,

```
PID=$(pgrep java)
```

works.

For multiple java processes it becomes more complicated. Manually, I run **pstree**, find the ancestor of the java process that I need first, then find the java process in question. Is it possible to do this in bash? Basically I need the functionality that in pseudo-code looks like:

```
Having `processname1` and `processname2`
and knowing that `processname2` is in the subtree of 'processname1',
find the pid of `processname2`.
```

In this example the java process will be `processname2`.

Answer (score 2):

Reformulating your psuedo-code question: find all `processname2` processes which have a `processname1` process as parent. This can be directly expressed using the following nested `pgrep` call:

```
pgrep -P $(pgrep -d, processname1) processname2
```

Here's the documentation for those flag straight from the `pgrep(1)` manpage:

> ```
>   -d delimiter
>          Sets the string used to delimit each process ID in the output
>          (by default a newline).
>
>   -P ppid,...
>          Only match processes whose parent process ID is listed.
> ```

Note that this will only work if `processname2` is an immediate child process of `processname1`.

Comment: I'm confused a bit by the description of -P in the man page. Would this work if `processname2` is not a direct child of `processname1`, but a grandchild etc (so there are other intermediary processes in the chain between them)? A quick experiment in the console shows that your recipe works only when `processname2` is a direct child.

Comment: Nope, this only works for direct child/parent processes. Added a remark to that effect.